# How does one pronounce $a \odot b$?

Tags: notation, pronunciation

I have seen authors use $\star$, $\ast$, $\cdot$ and $\odot$ to represent arbitrary binary operations on sets.  I'm wondering, what is the standard way to read or pronounce something like $a \star b$?  How would you read $a \odot b$?

Comment: How about "a odot b"? :P

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to ask is, is there a standard way to say $a \Box b$, where $\Box$ is meant to represent some arbitrary operation?  Saying "a operation b" doesn't really flow.

Comment: For an unspecified (or strange) operator, I would say "times" or "composed with".

Comment: @Jack: "composed with" seems inappropriate if the operator isn't associative.

Comment: @lenticcatachresis for what it's worth, I do read it like that always :D.

Comment: Should catch fine for students: a-tit-b :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, when I write such an operator into a problem, I use some variant of an asterisk or star (often a circled asterisk), reading it as "star" in my head.  If I'm not using some sort of star, I usually use a circled or boxed X-type symbol and read it as "cross" in my head.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest "sun" for $\odot$ (the standard astronomical symbol).

Answer (score 3):

I try to read from the context what it's supposed to mean. Most of the time I can extract how it's pronounced by just looking at the preceding text.

Without context I read $\odot$ as tropical multiplication and $\star$ as convolution (of some kind), but of course they can represent some other binary operation just as well. For $\cdot$ I could use either dot or times and $*$ could be times or star, I guess.

But most of the time there is a context, isn't it? If not, then my main priority would be to try and find the context.

Comment: What if the context is only that is it an operation?  For example, "Given a binary operation $\diamond$ that is associative and commutative, show that..."

Comment: Then I would pronounce it as it looks, i.e. star, dot, square and perhaps "circled dot" for $\odot$

Comment: Yeah, I would say the operation itself.  "ƒ∗g" uses the "asterisk operator", for instance, but in the context of engineering, I would not say "f asterisk g" or "f star g".  I would say "f convoluted with g" or "the convolution of f and g".  In other contexts, the same symbol would be read differently.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a⊙b as *"a op b"*

if is is the only binery operation being defined on the set a and b are from,
then I might drop it and write $ab$ and say *"a b"*

*"op"* since it is a operator,
and odds of there being two operators being used that I don't have words like:
star, asterix, cross, mod plus, circ etc, are pretty low.

But if it happened I would be saying "*c alt-op d*" or perhaps "*c op-two d*" (though if said fast that is hard to tell from "c op 2d"